# jquery $ 'Object' compared to getElementById() element?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors

Have run into jquery question while learning ajax.

$('div_hello'); 
  --> answers an 'Object'

document.getElementById('div_hello');
  --> answers an 'HTMLDivElement'

getElementById works ($ does not). For this experiement, I simply want to use innerHTML.

Not clear on how a jquery 'Object' differs from an HTML element. How would I ie set the html of the jquery object?

thank you

Comment: Worth a read, won't take you that long and will save you a **lot** of time in the long run: http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page esp. http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works and (of course) http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) like this:

```
$('#div_hello').html("content")
```

Or get the DOM element and use [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom%3aelement.innerhtml), like this

```
$('#div_hello')[0].innerHTML = "content";
//or
$('#div_hello').get(0).innerHTML = "content";
```

Note that your selector should be `'#div_hello'` like I have above, [`#id` selectors](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) are prefixed with a `#`, otherwise it's an [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) (and looking for a `<div_hello>` element).

The jQuery object is just a wrapper, it contains an array of references to DOM elements that it acts on, so think of it as "on top of" the DOM element. This is why `[0]` gets the element directly, because that element is first in the array that your selector found.

Comment: Thank you much all,
A lot of wheel spinning last night and you cleared it up in 5 mins -

works:
$('#div_hello').html("<h1>Hello World</h1>");

fails:
$('div_hello').html("<h1>Hello World</h1>");

Need the "#"

I wonder why w/o the "#" it didn't blow up (result was nop)

Comment: Without the #, you are selecting by element name. $('div') selects all <div> elements. $('#div') selects all elements with an id of "div". $('.div') selects all elements with a CSS class of "div". (I strongly recommend against using HTML element names as element ids or css class names. It just leads to confusion. I used it only for example.) The reason that $('div_hello') is legal is because you could be using the selector on a XML doc, which might have a <div_hello> element.

Comment: @James - I covered that in the answer :)

Comment: My bad for skimming too quickly and just jumping to Gary's follow-up where he still seemed confused by why $('div_hello') was failing. Apologies. :)

Answer (score 2):

> Not clear on how a jquery 'Object' differs from an HTML element.

A jQuery object is in fact completely different from the underlying DOM element. They are not interchangeable.

You should use the framework's native functions when dealing with `$()` objects, as Nick shows in his answer.

If you need to access the underlying element though, you can do so using

```
$('#div_hello')[0].innerHTML
```

Comment: Thank you much all,
A lot of wheel spinning last night and you cleared it up in 5 mins -

works:
$('#div_hello').html("<h1>Hello World</h1>");

fails:
$('div_hello').html("<h1>Hello World</h1>");

Need the "#"

I wonder why w/o the "#" it didn't blow up (result was nop)

Answer (score 0):

(formatted text this time)

Thank you much all,

A lot of wheel-spinning last night and you cleared it up in 5 mins -

works:
$('#div_hello').html("

## Hello World

");

fails:
$('div_hello').html("

## Hello World

");

Need the "#"

I wonder why w/o the "#" it didn't blow up (result was nop).

Thank you!